# Wordpress wp_nav_menu skipping items OR not sorting items

Tags: wordpress

I have a menu like this (called "Meny"):

```
Level1
...
- Level2
- ...
  - Level 3
  - Level 3 .. and so on.
```

However doing this in sidebar-menu.php:

```
    $options = array(
        'container'      => '',
        'echo'           =>  false,         
        'menu'           => 'Meny',
        'theme_location' => 'sidebar-menu',
    );                      
    $nav = wp_nav_menu($options);
```

Outputs all level1 and level2 items but always only the first level3 child??? I've double checked and I do have several level3 items in "Meny".. :S

If I remove 'menu' => 'Meny' it outputs all but then I loose the correct order!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the first menu is cached and used when wp_nav_menu is called the second time. It's weird it outputs the first level 3 childs though.

I used [`wp_get_nav_menu_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) instead and that worked!